# File upload fails; 503 error (plus COR error)

Tags: node.js, file, http-status-code-503

I currently have access control allow origin set to *

When I try uploading a file without authorization cors blocks my request

I get these errors:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://serverurl.com' from origin 'https://fronendurl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I'm using express and Node.js

This is my app.js file

```
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});
```

Comment: `I currently have access control allow origin set to *` show the code. There's something wrong with it, without the code we can't help you.

Comment: Just shared it. It may be because of the content type not sure.

Comment: Using only the `cors` middleware should be sufficient. It is responsible for setting the headers on every request for you.

Comment: What happens when you comment out the second `app.use`?

Comment: Same error. Doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Where are your routes. after or before the `app.use(cors())`. Also, show the response headers from a request, is the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header present?

Comment: Theres no response data that comes back. Cores blocks the request right away and i get a 503 in chrome

Comment: The 503 error is the problem you need to fix. Even if the 503 response had the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, you’d still have a 503 problem to fix. To troubleshoot the 503 error, you should check the server logs for your node server and see if there are any messages logged there. But a 503 typically indicates you’ve got a some other intermediary (a proxy or whatever) that’s trying to reach your server but failing (because of firewall issues, or the server not actually running, or whatever).

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming both `https://fronendurl.com` and `https://serverurl.com` are sitting on the same machine.

If you're creating a call, say AJAX to a different domain than your page is on from the same origin <= This gets blocked by the browser as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons.

For a quick medicine I would tryout moesif's [chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/) or [firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/moesif-origin-cors-changer1/).

Comment: Hey, there not front end is using netlify and backend is using heroku.